# Populate a third dropdown list based on two prior selected dropdown option

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm currently working on three dependent dropdown lists that would be populated based on the user's selected option. For example, the first dropdown list has the options of "Apples, oranges, and banana" if the user chooses "apples", the second dropdown would be populated by different options based on that answer.

My question is, I did this with the first two dropdowns basing on another question from stackoverflow. How do I go about doing this with a third dropdown list that's based on the two prior dropdown options?

I would really appreciate someone's help, and if it's not too much to ask, help me understand the logic behind it.

```
<?php
$inquirytype = array();
$inquirytype[] = "Feedback";
$inquirytype[] = "Inquiry";
$inquirytype[] = "Requests";
$inquirytype[] = "Complaint";

$position = array();
$position['Inquiry'][] = "Product";
$position['Inquiry'][] = "Where to Buy";
$position['Inquiry'][] = "Apply";
$position['Inquiry'][] = "Others";
$position['Complaint'][] = "Product";
$position['Complaint'][] = "Services";
$position['Complaint'][] = "Personnel";
$position['Complaint'][] = "Others";

$position2 = array();
$position2['Product'][] = "Good";
$position2['Where to Buy'][] = "Okay";
$position2['Apply'][] = "Nice";
$position2['Others'][] = "There you go";
?>

<div class="home">
    <form action="" method="POST">
    <select id="inquirytype">
        <?php foreach($inquirytype as $sa) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $sa; ?>"><?php echo $sa; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <p>
    <select id="inquirytype2">
    </select>
    <p>
    <select id="inquirytype3">
    </select>
    <p>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var s1 = document.getElementById("inquirytype");
var s2 = document.getElementById("inquirytype2");
onchange(); //Change options after page load
s1.onchange = onchange; // change options when s1 is changed

function onchange() {
    <?php foreach ($inquirytype as $sa) {?>
        if (s1.value == '<?php echo $sa; ?>') {
            option_html = "";
            <?php if (isset($position[$sa])) { ?> // Make sure position is exist
                <?php foreach ($position[$sa] as $value) { ?>
                    option_html += "<option><?php echo $value; ?></option>";
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
            s2.innerHTML = option_html;
        }
    <?php } ?>
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this. I added the same code for `inquirytype3` based on `onchangeS2` like `onchangeS2` based on `onchange`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var s1 = document.getElementById("inquirytype");
    var s2 = document.getElementById("inquirytype2");
    var s3 = document.getElementById("inquirytype3");
    onchange(); //Change options after page load
    s1.onchange = onchange; // change options when s1 is changed
    s2.onchange = onchangeS2;

    function onchange() {
        <?php foreach ($inquirytype as $sa) {?>
        if (s1.value == '<?php echo $sa; ?>') {
            option_html = "";
            <?php if (isset($position[$sa])) { ?> // Make sure position is exist
                <?php foreach ($position[$sa] as $value) { ?>
                    option_html += "<option><?php echo $value; ?></option>";
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
            s2.innerHTML = option_html;
        }
        <?php } ?>
    }

    function onchangeS2() {
        <?php foreach ($position['Inquiry'] as $sa) {?>
        if (s2.value == '<?php echo $sa; ?>') {
            option_html = "";
            <?php if (isset($position2[$sa])) { ?> // Make sure position is exist
                <?php foreach ($position2[$sa] as $value) { ?>
                    option_html += "<option><?php echo $value; ?></option>";
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
            s3.innerHTML = option_html;
        }
        <?php } ?>
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for this evgeny! I tested this out as soon as i saw your comment. There are some things that I want to change about this, but thank you for showing me where to start!

Answer (score 0):

I had a little play and put together a simple demo using ajax that binds all select menus to use a single event handler function. The event handler listens for `onchange` events and sends an ajax request to the designated PHP script - in this case it is the same page but could easily be a separate script/page.

The `$payload` variable is based upon the various array variables you have above but has been restructured to facilitate a lookup mechanism in response to the ajax request. There are comments throughout which should help. You could copy all of the above and create  a new document, save and run to test. Hope it will help!

```
<?php

    $payload = (object)array(
        'Types'         =>  array(
            'Feedback',
            'Enquiry',
            'Complaints',
            'Request'
        ),
        /* The following keys appear in the Types array and are menu items in initial dropdown  */
        'Feedback'      =>  array(
            'Positive'      =>  array('a','b','c'),
            'Neutral'       =>  array('e','f','g'),
            'Negative'      =>  array('h','i','j')
        ),
        'Enquiry'       =>  array(
            'Product'       =>  array('apple','banana','cherry','date','elderberry'),
            'Where to Buy'  =>  array('online','in-store','mail order','Del Boys Emporium'),
            'Apply'         =>  array('Office staff','Retail staff','Managerial position','Fluffer'),
            'Other'         =>  array('Let us know')
        ),
        'Complaints'    =>  array(
            'Product'       =>  array('Faulty','Incomplete','Poor quality','Damaged'),
            'Services'      =>  array('Ineffectual','Low-Grade','Unsuitable'),
            'Personnel'     =>  array('Lazy','Rude','Smelly'),
            'Other'         =>  array('Let us know')
        ),
        'Request'       =>  array(
            'Improvement'   =>  array('Bigger knobs','Smaller knobs','Louder whistle','Brighter colours'),
            'Assistance'    =>  array('Technical Assistance','Repairs','Customer services','Physical and mental support')
        ),

        /* The following does NOT appear in the Types array so will not be a menu item in 1st dropdown */
        'Bogus'         =>  array(
            'foo'           =>  array('bar')
        )
    );





    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['action'], $_POST['value'] ) ){
        ob_clean();

        $action=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'action', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
        $value=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'value', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );


        if( $action && $value ){

            /* create 2nd select menu options */
            if( property_exists( $payload, $value ) ){
                echo '<option selected hidden disabled>Please select';
                foreach( $payload->$value as $key => $arr )printf( '<option>%s', ucwords( strtolower( $key ) ) );
            }

            /* create 3rd select menu options */
            if( array_key_exists( $value, $payload->$action ) ){
                echo '<option selected hidden disabled>Please select';
                foreach( $payload->$action[ $value ] as $key => $item )printf( '<option>%s', ucwords( strtolower( $item ) ) );
            }
        }
        exit();
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chained SELECT menus using ajax</title>
        <script>
            const ajax=function(m,u,p,c,o){
                /*
                    m=Method,
                    u=Url,
                    p=Params,
                    c=Callback,
                    o=Options
                */
                const xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if( xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200 )c.call( this, xhr.response, o );
                };
                let params=[];
                for( let n in p )params.push( n+'='+p[n] );

                switch( m.toLowerCase() ){
                    case 'post': p=params.join('&'); break;
                    case 'get': u+='?'+params.join('&'); p=null; break;
                }
                xhr.open( m.toUpperCase(), u, true );
                xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' );
                xhr.send( p );
            }


            /*
                Callback function to populate dependant menu
                and modify other DOM elements
            */
            const ajax_callback=function(r,o){
                /*
                    r=response
                    o=options ( sent by ajax function )
                */
                if( o.menu != null ){

                    if( o.action=='Types' ){
                        /* when first dropdown changes, other dropdowns are cleared and the submit button is disabled */
                        document.querySelectorAll('select:not([data-action="Types"])').forEach( sel=>{ sel.innerHTML=''; } )
                        o.bttn.disabled=true;
                    }

                    if( o.menu === o.bttn )o.bttn.disabled=false;
                    else {
                        o.menu.innerHTML=r;
                        o.menu.dataset.action=o.value;
                    }
                }
            }

            /*
                The event handler that is invoked by changing the value
                of the dropdown menus.
            */
            const evtchangehandler=function(e){
                let method='post';
                let url=location.href;
                let params={
                    'action':this.dataset.action,
                    'value':this.value
                };
                let opts={
                    value:this.value,
                    action:this.dataset.action,
                    menu:document.querySelector( '[name="'+this.dataset.dependant+'"]' ),   // the target SELECT to be populated
                    bttn:document.querySelector( 'input[type="submit"]' )                   // the submit button to be enabled if final select is changed
                };
                let args=[ method, url, params, ajax_callback, opts ];
                ajax.apply( this, args );
            }



            /*
                Bind ALL select menus that satisfy the selection criteria
                using querySelectorAll. jQuery has other methods available
                to do the same thing
            */
            document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function(){
                document.querySelectorAll( 'form[ name="interaction" ] select' ).forEach( sel=>{
                    sel.addEventListener('change', evtchangehandler )
                });             
            });
        </script>

        <style>
            select,
            [type='submit'] { padding:1rem; width:300px; margin:0.25rem; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form name='interaction' method='post'>
            <h1>Chained SELECT menus using ajax</h1>
            <!--

                initial dropdown is populated based upon
                the $payload->Types array

            -->
            <select name='menu-1' data-action='Types' data-dependant='menu-2'>
                <option selected hidden disabled>Please select initial type
                <?php
                    sort( $payload->Types );
                    foreach( $payload->Types as $type )printf('<option>%s', $type );
                ?>
            </select>
            <!--

                subsequent dependant select menus will be populated
                dynamically based upon selection made in previous
                menu

            -->
            <select name='menu-2' data-dependant='menu-3'></select>
            <select name='menu-3' data-dependant='bttn'></select>
            <!--

                Form submit button is disabled until items 
                from all select menus have been chosen

            -->
            <input name='bttn' type='submit' disabled />
            <?php
                if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' )printf( '<pre>%s</pre>', print_r( $_POST, true ) );
            ?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I must say, there are various concepts here that im still not familiar with. I'm very new to php and i'm still picking up things as i go along. Let me just say this absolutely helped me. Both in what i was doing, and knowing things where i should improve on! Thank you again for this!